# Deleting a Gridview row when the DELETE button is pressed in the respective rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2008, sql-delete

This is my code I want to delete the row when that row's DELETE button is clicked and at the same time the database should also get updated.

```
    protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.CommandName.Equals("Delete"))
     {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = gvDetails.Rows[index];
        string productID = gvDetails.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
        string productName = row.Cells[1].Text;
        this.RemoveProduct(productID, productName);
     }
    }
public void RemoveProduct(string productID, string productName)
{
   DataRow dr;
   SQLConnection objcon;
   SqlDataAdapter objadp;
   objcon=new SqlConnection("Connecting string");
    try
    {
        objcon.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        objadp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select *from Bus_Table", objcon);
        objadp.Fill(ds, "Bus_Table");
        objadp.DeleteCommand = objcon.CreateCommand();
        objadp.DeleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE from Bus_Table where B_ID=" +int.Parse(productID);
        DataTable objtable = new DataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(objtable);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (dr["B_ID"].Equals(productID))
            {
                DataRow objrow = dr;
                objrow.Delete();
                objadp.Update(ds, "Bus_Table");
                ds.AcceptChanges();
                Response.Write("Bus Deleted");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        objcon.Close();
    }
}
```

When I am compiling this code am getting an error:

> "Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1'(my data source) unless DeleteCommand is specified".

When I put a breakpoint I noticed that the `RemoveProduct(string productID, string productName)` is not getting called from `gvDetails_RowCommand()` but the entry gets deleted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at these articles, it would explain in detail on how to delete single/multiple rows from gridview.
http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/06/15/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-from-gridview-with-checkboxes/
http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/06/14/how-to-delete-a-row-from-gridview-with-client-side-confirmation/

Answer (score 0):

There are some reserved command names that are recognized by a GridView:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

When a commmand event in raised in the `GridView` and the `CommandName` is one of the "reserved" ones, in this case "*Delete*", the `GridView` will try to use it's assigned `DataSource` (assigned using `DataSourceId`) to do the delete.

To solve the issue:

- Add a delete command to the SqlDataSource

or

- Change the `CommandName` on your button to something else and check for that in your code

Comment: @Rick Add the part of your GridView where the button is to your question.